# Did Blanche Adelaide LAPPAGE (b 1872) attend school?

Tags: england, 1870s, 1880s, school-records

Blanche Adelaide LAPPAGE was born in 1872.

Blanche’s mother died 1874, and her father remarried 1875.

Blanche cannot be found until the 1881 census in a Woolwich workhouse.  I have found no record of her with her father's second family or with any other known relatives.

I am trying to find where she was during the 10 year gap.

Would she have had to attend school?

Comment: Hi Susan, welcome. What type of records are you trying to find between 1872 and 1881? There are no other censuses during that period, so you are unlikely to find documentation of who she was living with during that time unless she was in an institution. Are you asking about Woolwich workhouse records?

Comment: I am looking for anything to tell me who raised this child.  I would assume she went to school but do not know about school records.  The reason I mentioned the workhouse is that is the only place I find her after her mother's death.  At that time she is on her own.